# Can I Adjust the Log Output Frequency in Salesforce CLI (sfdx/sf)?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I'm currently working with Salesforce CLI (sfdx) with my ci runner, and I've noticed that the log output frequency seems to be set at 1 second intervals. This is generating a lot of output, and I'm looking for a way to either reduce the frequency or customize it to my needs. Such as `sf package install` or `sf project deploy start`.

I've tried looking into the `SF_LOG_LEVEL` variable, but this solutions don't quite address my specific need to adjust the frequency itself.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Is there a way to configure the log output frequency in sfdx/sf? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.